# make stty raw -echo works with zsh or fish

Tags: zsh, fish, stty

I would like to know if someone has a way to make `stty raw -echo` works on fish or zsh.

I used it to upgrade a reverse shell but when I do fg i can't press "enter" etc

I got this result :

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fish restores terminal modes to a specific (and uncustomizable) set whenever it regains control, but not after each command, so you can run both commands in one commandline, like

```
stty raw -echo; fg
```

instead of separately.

Comment: Hi ! 
Thank you, the shell doesnt crash now but the autocompletion is not activated after that command, like I didnt typed stty raw -echo on fish
but it works on zsh so I'll use zsh ! 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: I think even this solution stopped working

Answer (score 0):

Fish deliberately ignores any changes made by the `stty` command. Or any other program which changes the tty settings for that matter. Whenever control is returned to fish from an external command fish sets the tty modes to a sane state. See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2315